# Поиск по строкам. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пример входящих данных:

```
0:15 15:15 40:40 15:0 0:30

0:15 30:30(стоп) 15:30 15:40 40:40(4)

0:15 15:15 40:40(3)

40:40(не считаем) 0:40 15:30 40:40(2)

0:15 0:30 40:40(1)
```

Нужно снизу вверх, справа налево найти количество *строк* в которых `40:40`, либо `30:30` идут подряд, как только (в данном случае при подсчете `40:40`) встречается `30:30` поиск останавливается, и наоборот.

В данном примере поиск на `30:30` останавливается, количество строк с `40:40` 4

Другими словами найти количество `40:40` или `30:30` с конца.

Вот мой код, но он работает не правильно:

```
s40 = 0 # Количество 40:40
s30 = 0 # Количество 30:30
flag = True # Выход из вложенного цикла
find = '' # Очко :) которое выпадет первым 40:40 или 30:30
for i in reversed(stroki): # Строки в обратном порядке 
    first = ''
    for j in reversed(points): # Очки в обратном порядке
        point = points['Point']
        if point == '30:30':
            if find == '': # Проверяем это первое очко или нет
                find = '30:30' # Если да, то дальше ищем только 30:30
            else:
                if find == '40:40': # Если мы ищем 40:40 а встретилось 30:30 поиск останавливается
                    flag = False
                    break
            if flag: # Если поиск не остановился, то продолжаем 
                if first == '': # Если это первое очко в строке то прибавляем количество на 1, иначе ничего не делаем
                    first = '30:30'
                    s30 = s30 + 1
        # То же самое и для 40:40
        if point == '40:40':
            if find == '':
                find = '40:40'
            else:
                if find == '30:30':
                    flag = False
                    break
            if flag:
                if first == '':
                    first = '40:40'
                    s40 = s40 + 1
    if not flag: # Выход из поиска
        break
```

Дальше смотрим количество `s30` и `s40`

Comment: Честно говоря я ничего не понял

Comment: @ПавелДурманов Найти количество строк (снизу вверх) в которых присутствует 40:40, до того момента пока не встретится 30:30 и наоборот. Более наглядно на примере

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
task = '''
0:15 15:15 40:40 15:0 0:30

0:15 30:30 15:30 15:40 40:40(4)

0:15 15:15 40:40(3)

40:40(не считаем) 0:40 15:30 40:40(2)

0:15 0:30 40:40(1) 
'''
refs = {'30:30': '40:40', '40:40': '30:30'}

def search(value):
    result = 0
    form = reversed(task.split('\n'))
    if value not in task:
        value = refs[value]
    for row in form:
        if refs[value] in row:
            break
        if value in row:
            result += 1
    return result
```

Еще такой вариант:

```
from itertools import takewhile

def search(value):
    value = refs[value] if value not in task else value
    return len(list(takewhile(lambda x: value in x and refs[value] not in x, 
                filter(None, reversed(task.split('\n'))))))
```

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо!

Comment: @АлексейТихонов поправил ответ

Comment: Можете подсказать как исправить Ваш код, чтобы она еще работала когда, например, 30:30 нет в списке, а 40:40 есть, и наоборот

Comment: @АлексейТихонов какое поведение вы ожидаете?

Comment: 0:15 15:15 15:0 0:30
0:15 15:30 15:40 40:40
0:15 15:15
0:15 15:15 40:40
40:40 0:40 15:30 40:40
0:15 0:30 40:40

Вот пример, 4 раза встречается 40:40, ни одного 30:30. Вывести количество 40:40 = 4 Все съехало, и таблица не получилась, но вы думаю поняли) В четырех строках есть 40:40, ни в одной 30:30, вывести количество 40:40

Comment: @АлексейТихонов поправил ответ

Comment: Не работает None

Comment: @АлексейТихонов поправил

Comment: Теперь работает не так) Теперь считает все 40:40, а не количество строк где есть 40:40